# regex trim the part of the string sql

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, extract

My data lives in Big Query. There is one column that needs REGEX extraction. The example of the string is below:

```
?src=abb_fh_uit*_source=h&_medium=cpm&my_campaign=abb_hc_hr
src=abb_fh_uit*_source=h&_medium=cpm&my_campaign=goal_healthcare
?src=abb_fh_uit*_source=h&_medium=cpm&my_campaign=goal_hr
?src=abb_fh_uit*_source=h&_medium=cpm&my_campaign=abb_hr_healthcare
```

My desired output is this:

```
my_campaign=goal
my_campaign=goal
```

Basically I need to trim everything but `my_campaign=goal`
The code I wrote is in SQL, below:

```
LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(my_column,r'my_campaign=([^&])')) AS my_campaign
```

it returns everything with my_campaign `my_campaign=abb_hc_hr, my_campaign=goal_healthcare` etc. How should I change the existing code to just grab my_campaign=goal?
Thank you.

Comment: If you only need rows with "campaign=goal" in it, why not just do `select *, 'my_campaign=goal' as my_column from t where my_column like '%my_campaign=goal%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You should use below

```
SELECT 
  LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(my_column,r'(my_campaign=[^&]*)&?')) AS my_campaign   
FROM your_table
WHERE LOWER(my_column) LIKE '%my_campaign=goal_%'
```

if applied to sample data from your question  - output is

```
Row my_campaign  
1   my_campaign=goal_healthcare  
2   my_campaign=goal_hr
```

Comment: But how would I trim to return only `my_campaign=goal`?

Comment: just add `WHERE LOWER(my_column) LIKE '%my_campaign=goal%'` - see updated answer